# XSLT: Not including more than one child elements when applying template

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Trying to move immediate child elements from root elements and then copying them under a new root element. Able to do it one child element but not sure how to apply `or` with in `select` statement.

Current XSLT for recursive child element:

```
<xsl:template match="Element1">
    <Information>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()!='Element1']"/>
    </Information>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Element1"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Element1/Element1">
    <Metadata>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Metadata>
  </xsl:template>
```

I want to apply same for another child element and tried

```
<xsl:template match="Element1">
    <Information>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()!='Element1'] | *[name()!='Element2']"/>
    </Information>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Element1"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Element1/Element1">
    <Metadata>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Metadata>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Element1/Element2">
    <Metadata2>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Metadata2>
  </xsl:template>
```

But it didn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try placing these templates into a group and use an empty template to remove those that you do not want.  Add a mode to the apply-templates

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="metadata"/>
```

to activate the group and then define templates in the group

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="metadata"/>
<xsl:template match="Element1" mode="metadata">
  ...
<xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Element2" mode="metadata">
  ...
<xsl:template>
```

for the metadata blocks.

---

Using a mode, your template would look something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Element1">
  <Information>
    <!-- use templates in the information group -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="metadata"/>
  </Information>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Element1"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- This template removes unspecified elements -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="metadata"/>

<xsl:template match="Element1" mode="metadata">
  <Metadata>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Metadata>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Element2" mode="metadata">
  <Metadata2>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Metadata2>
</xsl:template>
```

You probably have some other templates defining the content of `<Metadata/>` and `<Metadata2/>`.  Those should probably be in the mode as well.

Comment: Where would I use group in the xslt mentioned in the question?

Comment: Do you mean `mode`? I don't think `group` is a valid attribute on `xsl:template` or `xsl:apply-templates`.

Comment: Yes, mode.  Serves me right for answering a question from my iPad and without running it though a processor.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()!='Element1'] | *[name()!='Element2']"/>
```

... is always true for Element1 and Element2 - you can't chain two != expressions together like that because the expression will evaluate to true for everything.

You can simply match the Element1/Element1 and Element1/Element2 paths with templates that output nothing - then you don't have to have complex logic in the apply-templates expression inside .

Then call a named template (rather than using a match) from your root to output the Element1/Element1 where you want it to go.

Comment: Sorry, the code did not display: the expression *[name()!='Element1'] | *[name()!='Element2'] evaluates to true for all element names.

Comment: But it works fine for just `*[name()!='Element1']` but when I give `*[name()!='Element1'] | *[name()!='Element2']` it includes `Element2`

Comment: Because Element2 != Element1. So the first half or your expression is evaluating to true.